# Ubuntu 22.04 guest not complete boot (VirtualBox)

Tags: virtualbox, 22.04

Have just downloaded the .iso for Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and installed in VirtualBox (latest version v7.0.6). Everything seemed to install ok (although taking around 60 minutes, which felt like a long time). However, when I run the VM in VirtualBox, Ubuntu appears to boot ok, but only the desktop is displayed.

[image: Ubuntu showing the desktop only]

I've tried many combinations of small tweaks on the settings such as changing the RAM, number of processors, 3D acceleration on/off, etc. and nothing works.

Following a web search, I hit `ESC` during the boot and that displays some diagnostics. Nothing jumps out at me except that "GRUB failed boot detection", see image.

[image: GRUB fails boot detection]

Short of re-installing UBuntu from scratch, is there anything to try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying many different combinations of settings, I finally stumbled on `VM Settings > Display > Screen > Graphics Controller`.

This was set to **VBoxVGA** (presumably the default). The setting was changed to **VMSVGA** and now the Ubuntu guest works correctly.